# Create two column with vertical line in a presentation

Tags: beamer, listings

I'm doing a `beamer` presentation in LaTeX, and I want know if it's possible make something like this:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) would suffice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{tabularx,listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{tabularx,listings}
\lstset{
  language=C++,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily
}
\newsavebox{\codebox}% Used to store listings/code
\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\codebox}
\begin{lstlisting}
public class <Name> {
  ....
  ...
  ..
  .
  ..
  ...
  ....
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X|X}
  \usebox{\codebox}
  &
  \usebox{\codebox}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The fragile nature of [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)'s `frame` environment can be avoided by storing the content in a box (`\codebox`) and use it later. Or, you could explicitly use the `fragile` option for each `frame`. See [How to put C++ source code into `beamer` slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68085/5764). For a flavour in terms of keyword colouring, see [How to format C program code block nicely](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67379/5764).

See the [`listings` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) for more information on possible settings.